# What are R' Yaakov miLissa's commentaries on the m'gilos called?

Tags: jewish-books, acharonim, ketuvim, megillat-esther

Many a Jewish book is known colloquially by its title, like *Avne Nezer* and *More N'vuchim*. Many a one is known colloquially by its author's name, like the commentaries of *R' Moshe Alshich* and *Malbim* on *Tora* and *N'viim* (and *Malbim*'s on *K'suvim*; called "*Alshich*" and "*Malbim*" even though each volume has its own title), and *Bes Hab'chira* (called "*M'iri*"). And an occasional one is known colloquially by the title of another work of the same author's, like *Toras Moshe*<sup>[1]</sup> (called "*Chasam Sofer al haTora*").

[*R' Yaakov* of Lissa](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nesivos) wrote a commentary on each of the five *m'gilos*: *Imre Yosher* on *Rus*, *Taalumos Chochma* on *Koheles*, *Tz'ror Hamor* on *Shir Hashirim*, *Palge Mayim* on *Echa*, and *M'gilas S'sarim* on *Ester*. What are they called colloquially?

---

<sup>[1]</sup> This is also the title of the *Alshich* on *chamisha chumshe Tora*, incidentally.

Comment: I've heard it referred to as "the nesivos" on Rus , etc for nearly all of his sefarim.

Comment: @Yoni, if you've heard it that way from someone who would likely know what people call it, or from several people, that sounds like a good answer. (And thanks!)

Comment: @yoni I've never hear the books themselves called the nesivos on Megillah, but I I have heard it referred to as 'the commentary of the nesivos on the megillah, mainly because R Yaakov of Lissa is better known as the nesivos. Do people call the chavos daas 'the nesivos on 'Yoreh Deah' or the nesivos on hilchos pesach? That sounds a bit funny to me (but what do I know)

Comment: @Matt The Chavos Daas is very well known by that name so it is not referred to as "the Nesivos" on YD. But his seforim on Megillah are not as well known by their names. E.g. People say the Chofetz Chaim in Sfas Tamim writes, but don't say the Chofetz Chaim in Mishne Berurah, since everyone knows the MB. But again this depends on the circles you are in. (like in YU, the "Rav" is Rav YBS, in Brisk and many yeshivos it's Rav Velvel, etc.) I am just reporting what I heard...

Comment: This doesn't directly answer the question, but I heard Rav Aharon Feldman say everyone should learn the Nesivos on Haggadah shel Pesach, even though it's proper title is Maaseh Nissim.